# Update Db in EF5 with MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, entity-framework-5, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a project using Entity Framework 5 with MVC5. My Project is currently running.
I am trying to add a column in a table. But as we know that in EF when we add a field in model it drop and recreate the database, which i can`t do. 
One method for this is found code migration. But my manager is not allow me to use that(because its a big database project).

Please help me and suggest something for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I start using code first with Entity Framework, I was in the same situation as you. I was always running `Update-Database -F` and then watching all my tables get dropped and recreated, even for something as simple as renaming a field.

Versioning databases is hard, but it's much easier with named migrations (which I think it what you mean when you refer to code migrations). I know your boss is against the idea, but it's very flexible.

Essentially you run `Add-Migration -Name xxx` in your Package Manager Console and Entity Framework will scaffold a configuration class for you with the default commands (both for versioning `Up()` and `Down()`) it will execute when you `Update-Database`. If you don't like the commands, you can change them. You can even move data around if you need to (it's a bit fiddly though).

I think you have four options available to you;

- Use **code-first automatic migrations**: This is what you have at the moment, and doesn't give you enough control over what happens when you update your database. It's good for getting started in the earlier stages of a project, but becomes unwieldy after production.
- Use **code-first named migrations**: Gives you the control you need via `Configurations` - but your boss has prevented use from using it.
- Use **a database-first approach**: Database First allows you to reverse engineer a model from an existing database. So if you need to make a change, you would change your database first, and then regenerate your models using EF. This is usually favoured by DBA's, but it may mean that you have reimplement some aspects of your existing project.
- **Dont use entity framework**: It's possible that you could revert back to SQL queries, which your boss might accept and gives you the flexibility you need - but who needs that kind of pain?

Let me know if I can help further.

Comment: Hi,
I just wan`n ask what process migration follow.
Like, it create a backup of existing db and restore it again after updation in db structure ?
or it just update the _migrationtable or what?

Comment: Are you asking for the best approach to update a database that you have in production at the moment?